# A question about using a product name in a book title

Tags: copyright, trademark

Is it nominal use if I have a book title "I'm a weeble" based on the title of one essay in a book of essays?

The essay implies that I'm a weeble because I wobble but I don't fall down as metaphor for my life. That phrase is the advertising tag line for the weeble toys.   The whole book is not about weebles or the company. It is only three times where I reference them in the book. In the title of the book, the title of the first essay and within the first essay.

Comment: This has to be asked to a lawyer whom is more familiar with what's happening in your book and the applicable laws for where you live.